# Tampered vs Broken vs Teared

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, verbs

I recently bought a book from an online site. Some papers were “broken”. I want to send feedback to the online retailer. How can I say it correctly: “tampered” or “broken” or “teared”? Please help me to create a feedback mail.

Comment: What do you mean by *last day*?

Comment: @Tristan Mean the day i got the book

Comment: anish, that's not a common wording used by native speakers because it is unclear which day in particular, it is referring to.

Comment: last day means The previous day.ie yesterday

Comment: anish, in that case, it would be more common and natural to say *yesterday*.

Comment: OK.i heard such usage before in some movies and books

Comment: anish, did you hear non-native speakers use that?

Comment: Yes,From knowledge, I think Its a normal usage

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10824/discussion-between-anish-and-tristan)

Comment: I assume what you really want to say is that you found that some of the pages were torn when the package arrived.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither broken nor tampered make sense in your case. You would use *torn*, which is the correct form of your suggested "teared".

If you take a piece of paper and rip it in half, that piece of paper is *torn*. The paper is also torn if only small pieces are missing, or even if the paper remains connected after the tear.

[image]

From the dictionary definition of [*broken*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/broken) you would think it fits in your situation:

> **broken**, *adj.*
>
> 1. Forcibly separated into two or more pieces; fractured: *a broken arm; broken glass*.

But it doesn't. Note that the two examples are of items that would snap or shatter. A vase can be broken, but a book can't... A book can be ripped or torn or damaged, but it simply isn't idiomatic to say it's broken. This is what comes to mind when using *broken* in this sense:

[image]

As for [tampered](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tampered), you *definitely* don't want to use that.

> **tampered**, *v. intr.*
>
> 1. To interfere in a harmful manner: tried to tamper with the decedent's will; tampering with the timing mechanism of the safe.

When you say something has been *tampered with* (note the *with*, that's required) that means that you are accusing the company of *intentionally* modifying/changing/damaging the product before sending it to you. I don't imagine this is what you think happened, so I don't think this is the word you're looking for.

So, for a sentence to explain what you need to tell them...

> Some of the pages in my book are torn.

So *torn* would work fine, but most people would probably just say the book was *damaged*, and then add further detail if they thought it necessary:

> When my book arrived it was damaged; several of the pages were torn, and [insert anything else wrong with the book here].

Comment: i really liked this answer great definitions..Thanks! +1

Comment: I agree that a book can't be broken, but it is possible that a specific part of a book may be broken, e.g the spine of a book can be broken. This fits with your description of 'breaking' as relating to items which are stiff or brittle in nature.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this reference..It is the same situation which suits you..

> [Your address]
>
> [Seller's address]
>
> Dear Sir/Madam
>
> [Reference: Goods purchased through eBay on dd/mm/yy]
>
> On [date], I bought [item] from you for £[xx] however when [item] was received on [date] I discovered that it was damaged in the following way: [details of damage].
>
> The condition of the item was your responsibility up to the point I received it and accordingly I am entitled to [a refund along with a refund of all delivery costs] [a replacement]. I would request that you confirm in the next 3 days that you will provide this remedy and that you will cover the cost of the defective item being returned to you.
>
> Should I not receive this confirmation I will have no alternative but to raise a dispute through the eBay Buyer Protection dispute resolution process or to consider court action.
>
> I look forward to hearing from you.
>
> Yours sincerely

and for papers you can use **damaged book**.

Reference: [feedback e-mail](http://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/action/letter-for-a-refund-or-replacement-for-faulty-goods-bought-on-ebay/)

Update:

> tampered-past participle, past tense of tam·per (Verb)

Verb

```
1.Interfere with (something) to cause damage or make unauthorized alterations.
```

> teared-past participle, past tense of tear (Verb)

Verb

```
1.Pull or rip (something) apart or to pieces with force: "I tore up the letter".
```

> Broken- Past participle of break.

```
1. Forcibly separated into two or more pieces; fractured:
2. Incomplete: a broken set of books.
```

Comment: Ok.I want to know the exact difference between Tampered vs Broken vsTeared

Comment: How can i use these with in the case of a paper?

Comment: take the reference of this letter and as you want to say to the seller.write it in place of letter description.

Comment: "In my copy some papers where tampered".Is this correct?

Comment: i think the more appropriate is to write.. my copy of book is damaged and some of the pages are tampered.

Comment: OK.Please correct your above comment from tempered to tampered

Comment: okay I edited and if you found answer helpful kindly accept it.

Comment: Java and anish, *tampered* would not be a natural way of describing paper that is somehow damaged. It would be more common and natural to use the word *damaged* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/damaged?q=damaged when talking generally, before using particular words to describe the particular kind of damage to the book.

Comment: @Tristan.yeah i know that's why I recommend him to write that book is damaged for two time answer and a comments

Comment: Java and anish, there are particular words that can be used to describe the particular kind of damage to the book but, choosing one would require more information from anish. Two possible words are *ripped* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/rip_1?q=rip and http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/rip_3 *torn* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/torn?q=torn

Comment: anish, when talking about papers in a book, the correct word to use is *pages* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/page_1?q=page

Comment: That letter appears to be standard boilerplate. Is its use compatible with the SE site licensing? Also, "teared" is NOT the past tense of "tear". "Tore" would be correct in that context.

Comment: Tampered does *not* fit in this case. It implies that the company intentionally damaged the book before sending it, which I doubt OP thinks is the case! @anish