# For “yesterday”, what are the other forms we can use?

Tags: phrase-usage

For *yesterday*, what are the other forms we can use?

E.g.: *previous day*, *day before*, *last day*, etc. . . .

Here's the sentence that started this discussion:

> I have bought a book **last day** from an online site.

I wrote it in [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/tampered-vs-broken-vs-teared), and it was changed to *yesterday*.  But I think *last day* is right.

Here are a couple more examples:

> **Last day** I went to hospital.
>   **Last day** I was so happy.

Is the usage *last day* wrong?

Comment: We discussed this [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10824/discussion-between-anish-and-tristan), where Tristan and I claimed that "last day" can't be used as a synonym for "yesterday" in UK and US English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I followed the chat. Anish, the Op, seems to be claiming that "last day" means yesterday in Indian English.

In general, [Last day](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Last+Day) has a religious meaning which I did not know till now. But as a user of Indian English (*If there is such thing as Indian English which is **very different** from native English*), I have been using "last day" to imply the following meaning.

> The last time which should be implied by  a day a particular action happened.

For example: The last day, I watched a movie was 6 months back.

Generally, last day can be yesterday, day before yesterday or 1 year before yesterday. Now, I would not say "last day" to imply "yesterday" (*although I assume yesterday could be an option*). If something happened "yesterday", I would say it happened yesterday. For this particular example I would have gone with:

> I have bought a book **yesterday** from an online site.

Now someone may ask why I would go with yesterday. Well the answer is, no way a speaker would want his meaning to be unclear to a listener. The listener might ask,

> Last day means when? Yesterday? Or any other day?

So, if *yesterday* is the case, it would be said yesterday, otherwise *the last day* is fine with me.

Actually, its quite same with *the last time* except the fact *the last day* signifies a whole day something happened, not say for 2 hours IMHO. But I guess natives use *the last time* for a whole day too. However, according to me, Indians go with *the last day* often.

Comment: You can say: "Last year I went to France." which means, the year before this, or "The last year I went to France is 2008". So there's a big difference between "last year" and "the last year". Same for "last month" or "last week", so I assume it could also be good for last day